# How to pass database values via a constructor

Tags: java, sql

In creating software to save data into a database I have written two classes. One class defines the GUI with a form that users use to input data, the other saves the data into the database.

Data is passed to the database class via it's constructor, which is where I'm getting into trouble.

The code gets highlighted red (error) at:

```
tableValues.add(fullNames);
tableValues.add(iDNumber);
```

**The error:**

```
No suitable method found for add(String)  
method Vector.add(int, String) not applicable  
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Please help me get rid of the above error. I think the database class is alright, but I included it anyway. I think I made some error in the method getValues() in the GUI class.

**Part of the GUI class:**

```
private void addNewClientSubmitMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                
        String sql = "UPDATE Employees set age = ? WHERE id = ?";

        new UpdateAndQuerry(getValues(), "CLIENT", sql).main();

        // new JDBCExampleInsertRecords(getValues(), "CLIENT").main();
    }

public String getValues () {
        String fullNames = fullNamesJTextField.getText();
        String iDNumber = identificationNumberJTextField.getText();

        Vector<String[]> tableValues = new Vector<String[]>();

        // These two get highlighted:
        tableValues.add(fullNames);
        tableValues.add(iDNumber);

        Iterator<String[]> iter = tableValues.iterator();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            sb.append("'").append(iter.next()).append("'");

            if (iter.hasNext())
                sb.append(",");
        }
        return sb.toString();

    }
```

**The Database class:**

```
//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCExampleInsertRecords {
    public static String values;
    public static String table;

    public JDBCExampleInsertRecords (String values, String table) 
    {
        this.values = values;
        this.table = table;
    }

    // JDBC driver name and database URL
    private static String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
    private static String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:file:C:/WAKILI/WAKILIdb";

    //  Database credentials
    private static String USER = "sa";
    private static String PASS = "";

    public static void main () {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName(getJDBC_DRIVER());

            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(getDB_URL(), getUSER(), getPASS());
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

            //STEP 4: Execute a query
            System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "INSERT INTO " + (table) + " VALUES (NULL, " + (values) + ")";

            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            System.out.println("Inserted records into the table...");

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //finally block used to close resources
            try {
                if (stmt != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
            } // do nothing
            try {
                if (conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            } //end finally try
        } //end try

        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    } //end main

    /**
     * @return the JDBC_DRIVER
     */
    public static String getJDBC_DRIVER() {
        return JDBC_DRIVER;
    }

    /**
     * @param aJDBC_DRIVER the JDBC_DRIVER to set
     */
    public static void setJDBC_DRIVER(String aJDBC_DRIVER) {
        JDBC_DRIVER = aJDBC_DRIVER;
    }

    /**
     * @return the DB_URL
     */
    public static String getDB_URL() {
        return DB_URL;
    }

    /**
     * @param aDB_URL the DB_URL to set
     */
    public static void setDB_URL(String aDB_URL) {
        DB_URL = aDB_URL;
    }

    /**
     * @return the USER
     */
    public static String getUSER() {
        return USER;
    }

    /**
     * @param aUSER the USER to set
     */
    public static void setUSER(String aUSER) {
        USER = aUSER;
    }

    /**
     * @return the PASS
     */
    public static String getPASS() {
        return PASS;
    }

    /**
     * @param aPASS the PASS to set
     */
    public static void setPASS(String aPASS) {
        PASS = aPASS;
    }
} //end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why have you declared `tableValues` to be a `Vector` of `String[]`?  If you have `String[]`, then you would be expected add a `String[]`, not a `String`.

You don't need a `Vector` of string arrays, you just need a `Vector` of strings.  Change your declaration:

```
Vector<String[]> tableValues = new Vector<String[]>();
```

to

```
//      No []                            No []
Vector<String> tableValues = new Vector<String>();
```

Then the calls to `add` will be correct.